# iTunes not syncing complete playlists to iPod classic

Tags: data-synchronization, itunes, music, ipod

I have 1015 songs in the My Top Rated playlist on iTunes on my Mac.
Only 568 will sync to my iPod classic. I have checked that all the songs are 5 star rated and made sure that the "rules" state that only 5 star rated are to be included in the playlist.

I have turned off my iPod numerous times and restarted it. I have shut down iTunes on the computer and restarted it. I have tried to sync the iPod to iTunes many times using different USB ports thinking that might be a problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you create a static playlist containing these 1015 songs and sync that list to the iPod, do all the tracks get synced?